# If $X$ is a random variable and $Y = f(X)$ where $f$ is a measurable function, what is the meaning of $P(X|Y) = P(X|f(X))$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X$ is a random variable and $Y = f(X)$ where $f$ is a measurable function, then the meaning of $P(Y|X)$ is intuitive to me. However, when we have something like $P(X|Y) = P(X|\ f(X))$, then it seems that we are conditioning on something that depends on $X$, but $X$ doesn't actually depend on $f(X)$. In this case, why is it not the case that:

$$
P(X|\ f(X)) = P(X)
$$
by independence?

Comment: If e.g. $f(x)=x^2$ then a condition like $f(X)=4$ somehow "forces" $X$ to take a value in $\{-2,2\}$ so what you are saying ("$X$ doesn't actually depend on $f(X)$") makes no sense. In general is doesn't make sense to say that $Y$ depends on $X$ and at the same time $X$ does not depend on $Y$. They are mutually independent or they are not.

Comment: What is the "meaning" of $\mathbb P(Y\mid X)$? It does not make sense to speak of the probability distribution of a random variable conditioned on another random variable.

Comment: I mean $P(Y|X=x)$, sorry!